# Existe diferença em usar constantes ou variáveis em Classes?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Existe diferença em usar constantes ou variáveis em Classes?

Answer (score 5):

**Sim, existem diferenças**. Constantes não podem ser alteradas, independente de ser em classes ou não, é como se elas fossem `readonly` (somente leitura), além do mais elas sempre são `static`, ou seja o valor não é alterado para cada objeto:

```
class Foo {
   const a = 1;
   public $b = 1;

   public function __construct() {
        self::a = 2; //Irá causar erro
   }
}
```

Outro exemplo

```
class Foo {
   const a = 1;
   public $b = 1;

   public function __construct() {
        $this->b = 2; //Não irá causar erro
   }
}
```

Constantes tem estas características:

- Requer PHP 5.3.0
- São publicas sempre
- Não podem ser mudadas, o valor sempre será o do momento que foi declarada
- Acesso é estático (já que não tem necessidade de se alterar conforme estancia um objeto)

Uma dica, é possível usar a função [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.constant.php) (o que na maioria dos casos pode ser um tanto quanto redundante) tanto de uma `interface`, `classe` ou `define`:

```
<?php
define("MAXSIZE", 100);
echo MAXSIZE;
echo constant("MAXSIZE"); // mesma coisa que a linha anterior


interface bar {
    const test = 'foobar!';
}

class foo {
    const test = 'foobar!';
}

$const = 'test';

var_dump(constant('bar::'. $const)); // string(7) "foobar!"
var_dump(constant('foo::'. $const)); // string(7) "foobar!"
```

### Usando com [`spl_autoload`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload.php) (PSR-0 e PSR-4)

Existe uma pequena vantagem entre usar `const` se comparado com o `define` do PHP, quando usamos instalações via composer ou qualquer sistema que se baseia no PSR-0 ou PSR-4 se a classe que criarmos usar `define` e precisarmos apenas do valor da constante assim:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

define('FOO_BAR', 2);

class Baz
{
}
```

E tentarmos carregar assim, não irá disparar o autoload:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

var_dump(FOO_BAR);
```

Assim até dispara o autoload, mas não encontra a classe pois no PSR usamos:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

var_dump(Foo::FOO_BAR);
```

No entanto se fizermos assim:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

class Baz
{
    const BAR = 2;
}
```

E tentarmos carregar assim irá funcionar:

```
<?php
use Foo\Baz;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

var_dump(Baz::BAR);
```

Answer (score 4):

O próprio nome já diz tudo.

Constantes não podem ser alteradas. Já as variáveis, como diz o próprio nome, podem ser alteradas.

Então, resumidamente, use constantes quando você precisa de um valor ou uma informação importante que seja imutável. E as variáveis você deve utilizar em casos onde a informação pode variar.

Uma pequena correção é que quando se trata de classes a nomenclatura correta é *propriedades*, e não *variáveis*.

Em PHP, quando se trata de constantes temos algumas pequenas diferenças, como o fato de, por exemplo, uma constante poder ser declarada numa interface, diferente das propriedades que não podem ser declaradas lá.

Exemplo:

```
interface Searchable {
     const FLAG = 1;
}

class Search implements Searchable {}

echo Searchable::FLAG;
echo Search::FLAG;
```

## Recomendações

Um dos usos recomendados para constantes é simulação da enumeração em PHP.

Por exemplo, suponhamos que minha classe possua um método que aceite as ações "voar", "pousar" e "desligar". Não fica elegante você deixar o usuário ter que passar a string com essas opções, então nesse caso, creio que as contantes tem uma boa utilidade.

Veja:

```
 class Aviao {

      const ACAO_POUSAR = 'pousar';

      const ACAO_VOAR = 'voar';

      const ACAO_DESLIGAR = 'desligar';


       public function acao($acao) {
           if ($acao === self::ACAO_VOAR) {

           } elseif ($acao === self::ACAO_POUSAR) {

           } elseif  ($acao === self::ACAO_DESLIGAR) {

           } else {
              throw new Exception("Ação inválida");
           }
       }

 }




$airbuss = new Aviao();
$airbuss->acao(Aviao::ACAO_VOAR);
```

Outra forma importante de utilização das constantes é quando precisamos de utilizar "flags" para definir algum comportamento.

Suponhamos que você tenha uma classe de log, onde `1` significa "normal" e `2` significa "prioritário". Ficaria mais fácil usar constantes para definir essas "flags"

```
class Log {


       const NORMAL = 1;

       const PRIORIDADE = 2;

       public function write($value, $severity = self::NORMAL) {
            if ($severity == self::NORMAL) {
                 echo $value;
            } elseif ($severity = self::PRIORIDADE) {
                echo "Urgente: $value";
            } else {
               throw Exception("opção inválida");
            }
       }
}
```

Ainda utilizando uma outra forma de mostrar a importância das constantes, veja um exemplo da passagem de valores padrões para uma formatação de tempo. Se um dia a formatação mudasse, bastaria apenas mudar a constante, e todo o resto seria alterado.

Exemplo:

```
 $time = Time::create(20, 10, 0);

 $time->format(Time::DEFAULT_FORMAT);
```

**NOTA**: A partir do PHP 5.6 é possível definir `array` em constantes.

Comment: O código é apenas de exemplo, ou é bom a utilização de `Exception` neste caso?

Comment: É um exemplo. Eu poderia fazer assim caso fosse algo "mais grave" em relação ao argumento, por exemplo, se o cara passa um integer, ao invés de passar um objeto