# usando SFTP no php 5.3 com phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh

Estou tentando utilizar o **phpseclib** para fazer transferência com o php 5.3.
contudo não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.

meu teste eh esse código:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
               // include './phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php'; 
               use \phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

               $sftp =  new SFTP('192.168.0.65');

               if (!$sftp->login('oracle', '142536')) {
                     exit('Login Failed');
                }


               echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
               $sftp->put( '/home/oracle/teste.txt','./teste.txt',$sftp::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);
               $texto = $sftp->get('/home/oracle/teste.txt');
               echo $texto;

            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Contudo sempre retorna :

```
        ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\Net\SFTP' not found in C:\workspace\ssh_php\index.php on line 17
        Call Stack
        #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
        1   0.1068  127552  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
```

Como faço pra reconhecer o namespace em um codigo estruturado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova o comentário da linha:

```
// include './phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php';
```

Creio que o `\phpseclib\Net\SFTP` seja incorreto, deve ser algo como: `Net\SFTP`

Funciona até nesta ordem:

```
<?php
use Net\SFTP;

include './phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php';

$sftp =  new SFTP('192.168.0.65');
```

Agora se estiver usando isto: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net, devo lhe dizer que esta versão especificamente não usa namespaces ainda, o correto seria isto apenas:

```
<?php

include './phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php';

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('192.168.0.65');
```

O código é antigo e foi escrito antes do PHP suportar namespaces.

### Detalhamentos

Sobre o namespace, ele não faz o include sozinho como em outras linguagens, tem que usar include ou `spl_autoload`. No seu caso só o `include` já resolve com o `spl_autoload` poderá fazer o include baseando o namespace por um diretório, mas é preciso desenvolver isto primeiro, pois o `spl_autoload` não trabalha sozinho.

Se quiser conhecer e experimentar o `spl_autoload` recomendo que leia isto (não é algo para se preocupar agora):

- [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635)
- [Como funciona [modus operandi] o autoload em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175249/3635)
- [Existe diferença em usar constantes ou variáveis em Classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134140/3635)
- [class_exists está executando o spl_autoloader_register](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92858/3635)
- [PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80060/3635)

### PSR-0 e PSR-4

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: eh usar o include não funcionou, pois as dependências iam pedindo para ser incluídas. pesquisei sobre esse autoload e consegui essa função que me resolveu

**spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
                        include $class_name . '.php';
                    });**

Comment: @HagaHood de onde baixou essa lib? Pensei que eles não usavam namespace.

Comment: do github https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib

Comment: @HagaHood legal, estão usando namespaces nesta versão, deve ser uma fork.